# OneToMany relation is not reflected in the db using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects, which are referring each other. A **User** that owns a list of groups, and a **Group** which has one admin:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="admin")
    List<Group> ownedGroups;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="\"Group\"") // Group is a reserved word, use \" as a work-around
public class Group implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User admin;
    User admin;
}
```

There's a Group controller which I'm writing a bunch of end to end tests for it. In one of the tests, I create a group and tests that the admin is the user I expect.

```
Assert.assertEquals("wrong number of groups created for the admin", 1, user.getOwnedGroups().size());
```

While playing around with the db, I found out that there's no `owneddGroups` field in the `User` table, and there's no `User_Group` table created for this relation. I wonder how this field is persisted in the db then?

Comment: and you are not using `@Table` annotation? if using, please put that part too.

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Comment: is this your complete User and Group entity if so where is ID ?? Primary Key

Comment: Ofcourse it is not the whole class. The whole class definition is much larger. What do you want me to put here ?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting confused (in code) with the same 'admin' attribute ?

Comment: My question is "how owneddGroups is stored" ? There is no table, and no field in the table User

Comment: Are you saving instances of User alone OR both User and Group ?

Comment: Both of entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find an `admin_id` column in your table `group`.
This column contains an `id` from the table `user`.
This is your physical link between the two tables.

`ownedGroups` in the `User` entity is a slave field. It it only used for convenience, not for persistence, unless you reconfigure it.

when you call `group.getAdmin()`. Hibernate will `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id=<admin_id>;`.
This will return only one User.

when you call `user.getOwnedGroups()`. Hibernate will `SELECT * FROM Group WHERE admin_id=<id>`.
This will return a List of Groups.

Comment: So it means that it's calculated on fly ?